# How to center a div with all of its elements in html/css

Tags: html, css, position, center

i read that you can just use

```
.all {
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
}
```

but that doest work for  my case because the browser make it auto margin left and right , and it make the width to 50% but it doesnt make my div start from the center.
it do that and start in the left ,also all items get messed up.
this is my html code

```
<div class = "all">
        
        <div class="one">
            1
        </div>

        <div class="text">
        Januarry 1 2016
        </div>
    </div>
```

this is my css code

```
.all{
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px groove;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px black; 

}

.one {
    background-color:green;
    color:white;
    font-size: 150px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right:120px ;
    padding-left: 120px;
    padding-top:40px;
    padding-bottom:40px;
}


.text {
    font-size:25px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 30px;

}
```

so how can i center all of the div (class ("all"))

Comment: Have you had a look at the _many_ questions on this topic? There are two in the Related list at right. [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396145/how-to-vertically-center-a-div-for-all-browsers?rq=1) may be most relevant.

Comment: i want to center it horizontally